# Your AHK script for javaw priority?

Tags: java, batch, minecraft

I would like to know something for minecraft.

Following your post here : [How can I automatically change the priority of Javaw.exe when loading Minecraft?](https://superuser.com/questions/371413/how-can-i-automatically-change-the-priority-of-javaw-exe-when-loading-minecraft) .

Which AHK script you used for change the priority of javaw.exe please ?

Thanks in advance, i search everywhere but don't find yet..

Good Xmas.

B

Comment: You just asked everyone on Superuser which AHK script they used.  I think you want to add a comment to the question you cited instead.

Answer (score 0):

It's is the manual, [Process](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Process.htm).

So the code is pretty simple.

```
Run "C:\Users\Barrie\Documents\Program Files\Minecraft\Minecraft.exe", C:\Users\Barrie\Documents\Program Files\Minecraft
Process, Wait, javaw.exe
Process, Priority, %ErrorLevel%, AboveNormal
```

Param3 – AboveNormal in the example above – should be one of the following letters or words: L (or Low), B (or BelowNormal), N (or Normal), A (or AboveNormal), H (or High), R (or Realtime).

Note though it will just set priority for first javaw.exe it will find, not only for the one spawned by Minecraft.exe. Still, if you're not using java for anything else, it will work flawlessly.